# How to change bios config from dhcp?

Tags: bios, dhcp

I'm looking for any way to get/edit the configuration of the BIOS like active or deactivate secure boot without going manually to the bios.

The solution can be by using dhcp or other way.

Any way to do that?

Comment: BIOS (UEFI) does not deal with DHCP. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry, for unclear explanation. I just need to know if there is any way to access to the bios  by script to edit its setting other than using a keyboard and change it manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the general (and indeed all cases I am aware of) this is not possible.

For a start, DHCP is unrelated to BIOS/UEFI, so certainly as a "general" solution this is not possible.

It is conceivable that if a system has a secondary controller which can interact with the the system (like IDRAC, iLo, TSM or IPMI depending on brand) you might be able to configure its connection over DHCP and then somehow script your way through secureboot for that machine - but its important to know that DHCP is just providing an IP address to a machine to a machine with an out-of-band mini computer, and there is not a single standard here.

Comment: If i understand those potential solution (IDRAC...) are not generic, and may not work on some band?

Comment: @Unicorn that is what my second paragraph and the last 7 words of my answer said.

Comment: Thanks for the proofreading. +1